# Example of a pointwise convergent sequence not convergent in $L^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem and I have this solution. So the solution shows that $f_n-f$ is not even in $L^1$ space, when we need $\|f_n-f\|_1\to 0$ to show that the sequence converges to $f$. However, from my knowledge this only shows that $f_n$ does not converge to $f$. But we need to show that $f_n$ does not have a limit in $(Y, \|\cdot\|_1)$. Or, is there a fact that if a sequence converges to some limit in the $L^1$ space, then it must be pointwise convergent to that limit?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If a sequence $(f_n)$ converges to $g$ in $L^p$, then there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ that converges pointwise almost everywhere to $g$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok so the argument goes like: Then we have since $f_{n_k}\to f$, $f=g$ a.e., so $||f_n-f||_1\le ||f_n-g||_1+||g-f||_1=||f_n-g||_1$, so $||f_n-f||_1 \to 0$.

Comment: Or in words, the pointwise limit (if it exists) is the only candidate for an $L^p$ limit.

Answer (score 0):

A Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_n$ in a metric space with metric $d$ is a bounded sequence, because if $m,n\geq n_0\implies d(x_m,x_n)<1$ then $\forall n \;(d(x_0,x_n) \leq 1+\max \{d(x_0,x_j:j\leq n_0\}).$

$\|f_n\|=\int_0^1 |f_n(x)|\;dx=1/2+\log n$ so no subsequence  of $(f_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence. So neither $(f_n)_n$ nor any subsequence of it is $L^1$-convergent.